# Use Observable instead of Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got this function in one of my servlets:

```
private setValues() {
    this.config.socket.on('config.weather', (values:any) => {
      console.log(values);
}
```

I want to outsource so I get something like this:

```
private setValues() {
    this.config.load('weather').then((values:any) => {
      console.log(values);
}
```

any in the socket Service:

```
public load(key: string) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.socket.on('config.' + key, values => resolve(values));
});
```

This works for the first call, but when the socket fires again it wont be send to the `setValues()` function because a Promise only works once.

I think I have to use an Observable, but I have no Idea where to place it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a subject and now everything works fine:

```
public load(key: string) {
    let sub = new Subject();
    this.socket.on('config.' + key, values => {
        sub.next(values);
    });
    return sub;
}
```

and

```
private setValues() {
    this.config.load('weather').subscribe((values:any) => {
      console.log(values);
}
```